# Why would a moderator delete my answer to a closed question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

Over 10 years ago, probably not long after I joined Stack Overflow in fact, [I answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042601/how-to-use-openid-in-asp-net) with one line and a link - I know, I know, link-only answers are discouraged, but I was new and keen to get some answers under my belt.

Yesterday my answer was downvoted and deleted by a moderator. I'm not saying both actions were by the moderator, both just happen to occur yesterday.

But what I don't understand is why my answer was deleted when the entire question and all answers are no longer visible? My answer had gained 6 votes, the same number as the accepted answer which although contains a bit more text is ostensibly a link only answer as well.

When I noticed my answer had been deleted I edited it to contain a bit more information in the hope I could have it "undeleted". That's when I learned that moderator deleted posts cannot be undeleted and also when I saw the question had been closed - so my endeavour to resurrect my answer was nothing more than a folly - oh well. It's just a shame to lose 7% of the reputation I've slowly gained over a 10 year period :).

[image: The recently edited version of the answer suggests the asker start with the documentation and an introductory blog post with links to both.]

Comment: You did not lose any rep from the deletion since the post is old and your answer had more than 2 net upvotes. The answer was deleted because it's a link-only answer; [someone flagged it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2042893/timeline), and a mod deleted it. The edit to the answer *still* results in it being a link-only answer.

Comment: @CertainPerformance - thanks. I thought as much as the to why the answer was deleted, my edit was a vain attempt to salvage it! But if my edit would still be considered a link only answer doesn't that mean the other two answers are also link only answers and should deleted? Rest assured the answers I post now a never just links :)

Comment: “But what I don't understand is why my answer was deleted when the entire question and all answers are no longer visible?” - The question hasn’t been deleted.  **Well, it wasn’t, and then literally disappeared**.  However, answers to questions that are deleted, are also deleted.

Comment: @SecurityHound - as of a minute ago it has been deleted... but you are correct. It had been closed, not deleted when I posted this question.

Answer (score 5):

As I thought, and [confirmed by CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2042893/timeline) (although I don't have enough reputation to see the information), my answer was flagged as "link only" and therefore deleted by a moderator. I assume one of the users who voted to close the question also flagged my answer which resulted in both things happening on the same day, pure coincidence.

Comment: Just clarification "answer was flagged as "link only" " - there is no such flag, based on "low quality" queue it was likely flagged as "very low quality" (while controversial in general this is a reasonable flag for "link only" answer). There is also no reputation threshold where one can see what exact flags where used - one needs to be diamond mod for that.

Comment: Also, If you think it's no more a link only answer, You can reflag it using a custom mod action flag for undeletion. If a diamond agrees, it'll be undeleted. EDIT:It seems  the question is deleted as well, So this would seem impossible now, unless the question is undeleted as well